# Receiving messages back to my platform

Tags: sms, twilio

Use Case   SMS leaves my platform and goes out to a receiver (SMS).  I would like to attach some sort of custom identifier so when the user responds back to the SMS..and my platform received the message..I know how to internally route the response back in my platform.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set up a system where when the code is sent out

**For instance:**

Code - 11832

The user then has to enter this code on your website. A program will then match to see if it's the identical code. So you are then able to log the information

No expert on this though and Where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

There isn't really a great way to attach an identifier to the message itself.  You could force the user to prepend/append a code in their reply, but depending on your specific scenario that might not be a great user experience.

Another option is to save the to/from phone number as a unique pair when you send the message.  Then as your application receives replies you can check the incoming to/from phone number against what you saved.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Do you think it feasible to programmatically create a phone number that I user for the back and for SMS....simply tying the number to an existing messaging service.  When I am done needing the number ..simply remove the number or reuse for use on another thread

Comment: You could totally buy and sell numbers on the fly to use as you need them. Check out the API for [searching for](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers) and then [buying numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#list-post).